# Query to add values of two columns

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have a table `emp`, which has 3 columns: `EmpId, Name & Salary`. I altered the table and made a new column `NewSalary`. Now i want to multiply `Salary` by 1.2 (or any other value)  and store the result in `NewSalary`. What is the Sql query for this?

I tried

```
SqlCommand search1 = new SqlCommand("update emp set NewSalary = Salary * 1.2", con);                

SqlCommand search2 = new SqlCommand("select NewSalary, Salary, Salary *1.2 as NewSalary from emp", con);
```

but it's not working.

Comment: The first update statement looks correct to me. Do you get any error messages at all? What does the rest of the code look like? Just defining a command is not enough, I assume you do execute the command at some point as well?

Comment: Please don't erase changes done by others by making yours.

Comment: Why you need new field at all ? Is it not enough `update emp set Salary = Salary * 1.2` ?

Comment: Both the queries are not working or what? and you are storing the result in wSalary or its a typo?

Comment: well i need to calculate employees salary into newsalary and i need to display both old salary and new updated salary.

Comment: @SchmitzIT  i donot get errors for the 1st code but 'm getting errors for the second

Comment: @Meherzad -- 1st query is working but the second query in not working

Comment: @Meherzad s your rite i need to store in wSalary

Comment: Error is because 2  columns are having the same name. change the name to of salary *1.2 to something else

Comment: its actually NewSalary by mistake i typed as wSalary

Comment: @Meherzad sorry didn get u

Comment: "select NewSalary, Salary, Salary *1.2 as NewSal from emp"     Now try running your query.

Comment: @Meherzad no its not working

Comment: Please post he error that is displayed.

Comment: what is types of columns ?

Comment: your second code is not wrong.i think your colunms types are not numeric types.

Comment: @Meherzad  its hvin exception

Comment: @LütfullahKus  its of varchar(50)

Comment: @user1986144 cast your varchar column as follow and then multiply it  `CAST(salary AS UNSIGNED) * 1.2`

Comment: hmm.then try this.
"select NewSalary, Salary, Convert(float,Salary) *1.2 as NewSalary from emp"

Comment: @user1986144, just use correct casts and it will work: `update emp set Salary = CAST(CAST(Salary as float) * 1.2 as varchar(50))` BTW salary should be numeric instead of varchar...

Comment: @0x69 thank u n 'm stuck again...so hw do i  search from a text field  i,e..SqlCommand search = new SqlCommand("select * from emp where EmpId=('" + TextBox1.Text + "')");

Answer (score 0):

try this.

> "select NewSalary, Salary, Convert(float,Salary) *1.2 as NewSalary
>   from emp"

Comment: SqlCommand search = new SqlCommand("select * from emp where EmpId=('" + TextBox1.Text + "')");

Comment: it was helpful... n now again 'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Convert'.
here is a tip.use SqlParameters for send Parameters to sql.not like " + textboxt.text + ".

```
SqlCommand search = new SqlCommand("select * from emp where EmpId=@emId",sqlconnection);
serach.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emId",Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text));
```